# fontawesome 404 ttf and woff

Tags: android, cakephp, truetype, woff

I developed a Cakephp app which uses fontawesome and I've hosted it on my android tablet (using KSWEB) for work purposes. Fontawesome works ok when hosted on windows server (even server2go) but when hosted on my tablet, it gives two 404 regarding fontawesome's ttf and woff files and shows icons as weird characters.

I don't have the slightest clue of what's going on, and paths are ok since it works when hosted elsewere, maybe I'm missing some particular declaration.

I don't know, please help.

Comment: No answer? Damn i guess it is harder than i thought. Help appreciatted people.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information? In the source code, where is it looking for the font awesome files? Could be it's using the wrong directory separator if it works on Windows but not on a Linux-based server.

Comment: Well, managed to "solve" my problem by using bootstrap default icons and not fontawesome's. Not what I call a win but a way out.